# Show that $|f(x)|/|x|^{a + \epsilon} \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ for all $\epsilon < 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ be a nonzero function with compact support. Assume that $|f(x)|/|x|^a$ is bounded around a neighborhood of $0$, where $a \geq 0$. Can we show that this implies that $|f(x)|/|x|^{a + \epsilon} \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ for all $\epsilon < 1$?

The idea that I have is to split the integral over $\mathbb{R}$ as a union of a disjoint sets. Suppose we are given that the neighborhood around where the function is bounded is given by $N_\delta(0)$. I think we can assume without loss of generality that $\delta < 1$. My idea is to write $\mathbb{R} = N_\delta(0) \cup (N_1(0) \setminus N_\delta(0)) \cup N_1(0)^c$. The integral over the last of these two sets works out I think, but I cannot get anything over the neighborhood of $0$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$This idea works, you just had to continue.

Let $\delta>0$ and $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|\cdot|x|^{-a}<M$ for all $x,|x|<\delta$, and fix $0<\epsilon<1$. Such $\delta$ exists because neighbourhoods of zero are open at zero.

Then: $$\begin{align}\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|^{a+\epsilon}}\d x&=\int_{-\delta}^\delta\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|^a}|x|^{-\epsilon}\d x+\int_{|x|\ge\delta}|f(x)|\cdot|x|^{-a-\epsilon}\d x\\&\le 2M\int_0^\delta|x|^{-\epsilon}\d x+\delta^{-a-\epsilon}\int_{|x|\ge\delta}|f(x)|\d x\\&\le\frac{2M}{1-\epsilon}\cdot\delta^{1-\epsilon}+\|f\|_1\cdot\delta^{-a-\epsilon}\\&<\infty\end{align}$$

So indeed $x\mapsto|f(x)|\cdot|x|^{-a-\epsilon}\in L^1(\Bbb R)$.